# How to generate varying random numbers?

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
   int i,sample;
   clrscr();
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      sample=rand();
      printf("%d\n",sample);
   }
   getch();
}
```

For the above code, every time I execute, the same random numbers 346,130,10982,1090,11656 are generated. But I need to generate varying random numbers when I execute the code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [random seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) that changes each time you run the program. One common approach is to use the current time.

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: but now it shows an error "not an allowed type". What to do?

Comment: ah. better use an allowed type then. what does the error refer to?

Comment: Did you `#include <time.h>` ?

Comment: yes.I haven't included time.h and so the error occurs. Now I have got the output

Answer (score 2):

You need to [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) your [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Read [rand(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) & [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) man pages.

As [guest answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22890679/841108) you could use the current time (with `#include <time.h>`, see [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html)) as a seed.

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
srand((unsigned)now);
```

But on Linux you could also use the `/dev/urandom` device (at least for seeding) - see [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) for more, or the current pid (see [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) to get it using `#include <sys/type.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`).

```
{ unsigned s = (unsigned)getpid();
  FILE* f = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
  if (f) { fread (&s, sizeof(s), 1, f); fclose(f); };
  srand(s);
}
```

If using `random`, replace `srand` with `srandom` ....

BTW, `random(3)` is supposed to be a better PRNG than `rand(3)`

Also, you might read your random numbers directly from `/dev/urandom` (or even `/dev/random` which could block!); but it is generally not worth the effort. And `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` is available on Linux but probably not on many other systems.